# Authentication when using angularjs and passportjs

Tags: angularjs

I am currently using passportjs for authenticaton.

I have come across a stage where i need to ensure the user is authenticated if the url is typed in the browser/ I have been using the passportja example which has the following:

```
app.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
console.log('get admin');
res.render('admin', { user: req.user });
});
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
res.redirect('/login')
}
```

I am using angularjs for routing so my get does not work and run the ensure authenticated.

How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS, you need to restrict the display of templates to the user.

So, let us say you have the following code in AngularJS:

```
$routeProvider.when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/admin-page.html'
});
```

When the user tries the `/admin` route, AngularJS will then request the template `/partials/admin-page.html`.

Thus, in your nodeJs server, you then implement the following code:

```
app.get('/partials/admin-page.html', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin', { user: req.user});
});
```

Comment: hi tried the suggestion but it never gets into the app.get. The url is definitely correct.

Comment: Also not sure if this makes a difference but have used  yeoman for client side which contains everything including views in the app folder. The server.js file sits at the upper level.